# Fourier transform of the product of a Heaviside distribution and a function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform, complex-integration

I am trying to calculate the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}[H(t-\tau)x(t),t,\omega]$ where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside distribution and x(t) is a well behaved real function (like the position of a bead in a trap. Nothing crazy, nothing diverging, everything continuous, etc). 
It seems relatively straightforward but in the end, I obtain $\mathcal{F}[H(t-\tau)x(t),t,\omega]=\mathcal{F}[x(t),t,\omega]$ and can't figure out why the heaviside distribution just seems to vanish.

I'd like to understand what I do wrong and what I should do instead.

**Here is my attempt :**

for compactness, I will use the notation $\mathcal{F}[f(t),t,\omega] = \hat{f}(\omega)$. 
$$
\mathcal{F}[H(t-\tau)x(t),t,\omega]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(t-\tau)x(t)e^{-i \omega t}dt \\
\mathcal{F}[H(t-\tau)x(t),t,\omega]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-i (\omega-\omega_1)\tau}\hat{H}(\omega-\omega_1)\hat{x}(\omega_1)d\omega_1
$$
where I used both the product rule and the translation rule.

I then use the fact that $\hat{H}(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{i \pi \omega}+\delta(\omega)\right)$ and separate the dirac part of the integral, which is pretty trivial. 
$$
\mathcal{F}[H(t-\tau)x(t),t,\omega]=\frac{1}{2}\hat{x}(\omega)+\frac{e^{-i \omega \tau}}{2 i \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\hat{x}(\omega_1)e^{i \omega_1 \tau}}{\omega-\omega_1}d\omega_1
$$

Now I have to compute this integral that has a pole on $\omega$. To do this, I have to use the imaginary half plane because of the $e^{i \omega_1 \tau}$ term. 
I can then write the integral on a closed loop containing no poles : 
$$
\int_{\omega+\epsilon}^R \frac{\hat{x}(\omega_1)e^{i \omega_1 \tau}}{\omega-\omega_1} d\omega_1 + 
\int_0^\pi \frac{\hat{x}(R e^{i \theta})e^{i R e^{i \theta} \tau}}{\omega-R e^{i \theta}} i R e^{i \theta} d\theta + 
\int_{-R}^{\omega-\epsilon} \frac{\hat{x}(\omega_1)e^{i \omega_1 \tau}}{\omega-\omega_1} d\omega_1 + 
\int_\pi^0 \frac{\hat{x}(\omega + \epsilon e^{i \theta})e^{i (\omega + \epsilon e^{i \theta}) \tau}}{\omega-(\omega + \epsilon e^{i \theta})} i \epsilon e^{i \theta} d\theta = 0
$$
when $R\to\infty$ and $\epsilon\to 0$ : 
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{\hat{x}(R e^{i \theta})e^{i R e^{i \theta} \tau}}{\omega-R e^{i \theta}} i R e^{i \theta} d\theta \to 0 \\
\int_{-R}^{\omega-\epsilon} \frac{\hat{x}(\omega_1)e^{i \omega_1 \tau}}{\omega-\omega_1} d\omega_1 + 
\int_{\omega+\epsilon}^R \frac{\hat{x}(\omega_1)e^{i \omega_1 \tau}}{\omega-\omega_1} d\omega_1 \to \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\hat{x}(\omega_1)e^{i \omega_1 \tau}}{\omega-\omega_1} d\omega_1
$$
The remaining term is 
$$
\int_\pi^0 \frac{\hat{x}(\omega + \epsilon e^{i \theta})e^{i (\omega + \epsilon e^{i \theta}) \tau}}{\omega-(\omega + \epsilon e^{i \theta})} i \epsilon e^{i \theta} d\theta = -\int_0^\pi \hat{x}(\omega + \epsilon e^{i \theta})e^{i (\omega + \epsilon e^{i \theta}) \tau} i d\theta \\
\int_\pi^0 \frac{\hat{x}(\omega + \epsilon e^{i \theta})e^{i (\omega + \epsilon e^{i \theta}) \tau}}{\omega-(\omega + \epsilon e^{i \theta})} i \epsilon e^{i \theta} d\theta \to -i \int_0^\pi \hat{x}(\omega)e^{i \omega \tau} d\theta = -i\pi \hat{x}(\omega)e^{i \omega \tau}
$$

In the end, we can rewrite this integral as $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\hat{x}(\omega_1)e^{i \omega_1 \tau}}{\omega-\omega_1} d\omega_1 = i\pi \hat{x}(\omega)e^{i \omega \tau}$. 
Therefore my equation becomes : 
$$
\mathcal{F}[H(t-\tau)x(t),t,\omega]=\frac{1}{2}\hat{x}(\omega)+\frac{e^{-i \omega \tau}}{2 i \pi} i\pi \hat{x}(\omega)e^{i \omega \tau} = \hat{x}(\omega)
$$

If I then take the inverse Fourier transform of this , I obviously do not come back to what I started with ... 
So obviously this has to be wrong, but I cannot understand where I go wrong.

What is false in here, and what should I do to get the right result ? 
(and what is the right result, by the way ?)

Comment: This part is true:
$$\mathcal F[t \mapsto x(t) H(t - \tau)](\omega) =
\frac 1 2 \hat x(\omega) +
\frac {e^{-i \tau \omega}} {2 \pi i} \operatorname{v. \! p.} \int_{\mathbb R}
 \frac {\hat x(\xi)} {\omega - \xi} \, e^{i \tau \xi} d\xi$$
(since the convolution of a distribution with a test function is well-defined). If, for a given $\tau$, $x(t) \equiv x(t) H(t - \tau)$, then the second term is indeed $\hat x(\omega)/2$. Generally, $\hat x$ may not be analytic at a point on the real axis, or not analytic in the upper/lower half-plane, or may not decay uniformly on upper/lower semicircles.

Comment: @Maxim so if I get what you mean, you are saying that even though the real space function $x(\omega)$ is well behaved, it doesn't mean that it's Fourier space counterpart $\hat{x}(\omega)$ is (of course, I didn't think about that. That makes sense). 
Do you see any way I could still write this in Fourier space as the product of $\hat{x}(\omega)$ and something, so I could get an expression for $\hat{x}(\omega)$ (or do I have to give up using Fourier for this application altogether) ?

Comment: To be more precise, $\hat x$ is well-behaved, but that means infinitely differentiable and of rapid decay on $\mathbb R$, it doesn't mean analytic. If you have a specific $x$ in mind, there might be simpler methods to evaluate the transform.

Comment: @Maxim the idea of what I'm trying to do here is that I have a behaviour equation on $x(t)$ and am trying to translate it in fourier space to try to simplify the problem to solve for $\hat{x}(\omega)$. So all I have is properties on $w(t)$ and $\hat{x}(\omega)$ based on the physical constraints. For example, $x(t)$ is a deterministic response, which I think means that there are no poles and that the function is analytic in the upper half plane (though not necessarily on the real axis).

Comment: Sorry, I think this is a bit too vague. I don't understand where $H(t - \tau)$ comes in.

Comment: @Maxim Sorry about that. To be clearer the equation I'm trying to work with in Fourier space is $\gamma \frac{d x(t)}{dt} + (\kappa_i + \frac{\Delta\kappa}{\tau} t H(t) H(\tau-t) + \Delta\kappa H(t-\tau)) x(t) = D \eta(t)$ where $\eta(t)$ is a white noise term. 
My issues with Heaviside distributions come in the second term of the left hand side. 
I'm trying to solve $\hat{x}(\omega)$ as a function of the noise term, but to do that, I need to be able to transform this into a differential equation I can solve.

Comment: You might want to create a separate question about how to solve the equation, which, if I understand correctly, is an SDE, not an ODE. I'm not sure Fourier transform is going to help: if $\eta$ is in fact a random process, then what is its Fourier transform?

Comment: @Maxim Yeah, I am indeed now understanding that trying to go to Fourier was a mistake in that case (it usually simplifies this kind of equations. In this case, it might make it worse). 
As for how to treat the noise, I just keep its Fourier transform as a noise term and have integrals over the noise. I need to have an expression to work with, not to get a fully explicit expression of $\hat{x}(\omega)$ or $x(t)$. It's the nature of the beast. Until you take some kind of average, you won't get rid of the noise terms. 
Still the question of how to fourier transform this is interesting to me.

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform of $H(t)x(t)$ is $A \hat{x}(\omega) + \hat{x} \ast pv(\frac{B}{\omega})$ and the second term doesn't simplify in general. If $\hat{x}$ is analytic, to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \hat{x}(w) \frac{1}{\omega-w}dw$ as a contour integral you need to take the mean value of two integrals $$\frac12 (\int_{C^+}  \hat{x}(w) \frac{1}{\omega-w}dw+\int_{C^-}  \hat{x}(w) \frac{1}{\omega-w}dw)$$ where $C^+,C^-$ are the real axis with a small indentation above/below $w = \omega$.

If $\hat{x}(z)$ decreases fast enough as $\Im(z) \to \infty$ the residue theorem applies and you get $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \hat{x}(w) \frac{1}{\omega-w}dw =\frac12 \int_{C^-}  \hat{x}(w) \frac{1}{\omega-w}dw= i \pi Res(\hat{x}(w) \frac{1}{\omega-w}, \omega) = -i\pi \hat{x}(\omega)$$
indicating that $x$ was indeed supported on $t > 0$.

If instead $x$ was supported on $t< 0$ it is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \hat{x}(w) \frac{1}{\omega-w}dw =\frac12 \int_{C^+}  \hat{x}(w) \frac{1}{\omega-w}dw= -i \pi Res(\hat{x}(w) \frac{1}{\omega-w}, \omega) = i\pi \hat{x}(\omega)$$ as expected from the fact that $pv(\frac{1/i\pi}{\omega})$ is the Fourier transform of $sign(t)$.

Comment: I don't get your first part, why are you using the mean value of those two integrals ? I also don't see how the fact that your function is supported on R+ or R- comes in in your calculation. It seems to me that you are writing the same residue and giving two different results without real justification (just to be clear, because this last sentence can seem harsh, I'm not criticizing, just asking for clarification, because I didn't understand the justification).

Comment: @SamuelAlbert $1/\omega$ is not a distribution, what is a distribution is $pv(1/\omega)$ and $pv(1/\omega)+C\delta(\omega)$. For $\hat{x}$ analytic, integration wrt $pv(1/\omega)$ is the [mean value of two contour integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem) passing below and above the pole, so (if the residue theorem applies) the sign of the residue is not the same in each case, as expected from the fact $pv(1/\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $sign(t)$.

Comment: To see what is happening, you can integrate by parts to make $\log |\omega|$ the primitive of $pv(1/\omega)$ appear, then the two contours integals correspond to integrals wrt $\log(\omega\pm i \epsilon)$.

Comment: The reason for the confusion might be the typo in the last formula, $\int_{C^+}$ should give $-i \pi \operatorname{Res}$. The signs, however, depend on the FT definition. With the convention used in the question, the p.v. integral of $\hat x(w)/(\omega - w)$ gives $+i \pi \hat x(\omega)$ for $x$ supported on $t > 0$.